# Yii2 - active form set empty value on update

Tags: yii, yii2

I am trying to make update password functionality, but at the moment when I use active record to create form, password field is populated with user password. How can I omit this? This is the code used for generating password field (rest of the form is standard active form template):

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
```

Comment: did you try $form->field($model, 'password', ['value'=> ''])->passwordInput();

Or maybe u can reset the $model->password='' value reset

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['value'=>'']) ?>
```